# Auto Scaling is free or cost for storing snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to create AMI. By default if we create image it creates snapshot. Is the creation of snapshot chargeable?

If creation is not chargeable, can we keep snapshot and AMI in our account, after terminating EC2 instances. Because AWS does not entertain idle usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pay for *creating* a Snapshot, but you pay for **storing** a Snapshot based on its size and storage duration. You can find more details on the [EBS Pricing Page](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/?nc1=h_ls).

AutoScaling as a service is free, but you pay for the resources it creates, namely the instances it runs. As a prerequisite, you need a Launch Configuration with an AMI. If you don't use one of the pre-built AMIs from AWS, you will also pay for the storage costs of the underlying Snapshot.

Comment: snapshot > 1 GB will be charged but snapshot <1 GB not chargeable? correct me if i am wrong

Comment: What gives you that impression? You pay for how much storage the snapshot consumes, i.e. the size of the EBS volume and for successive snapshots the size of the deltas.